# Python logging: ルートロガーのデバッグレベルをINFOにしたけど、logger.infoで出力されない理由

Tags: python

## 環境

- Windows10
- Python 3.6.6

## やりたいこと

Pythonのlogging機能を使って、コンソールとログファイルにログを出力したいです。
`other`という名前のlogger以外は、すべてINFOレベルで出力したいので、ルートロガーのレベルをINFOにしました。

```
$ ls
logger-main.py
fuga.py
logging.yaml
```

#### logger-main.py

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml
from fuga import Fuga


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open("logging.yaml").read()))

    f = Fuga()
```

#### fuga.py

```
import logging
import yaml

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Fuga:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug("Fuga Constructor in debug")
        logger.info("Fuga Constructor in info")
```

#### logger.yaml

```
version: 1
formatters:
  customFormatter:
    format: '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(module)s : %(message)s'
handlers:
  fileRotatingHandler:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    filename: logfile/logger.log
    when: 'D'
    formatter: customFormatter
  consoleHandler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: customFormatter
loggers:
  other:
    level: DEBUG
root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [fileRotatingHandler, consoleHandler]
```

#### 問題

`$ python logger-main.py`を実行しましたが、標準出力とログファイルには何も出力されませんでした。
ルートロガーをINFOレベルに設定したので、fugaのinfoログは出力されると思っていました。

以下のように、logger.yamlの`loggers`部分に`fuga`を追加したら、

```
loggers:
  other:
    level: DEBUG
  hoge:
    level: DEBUG
```

次のように、標準出力とログファイルに出力されていました。

```
2019-03-16 16:22:13,791 : DEBUG : fuga : Fuga Constructor in debug
2019-03-16 16:22:13,791 : INFO : fuga : Fuga Constructor in info
```

#### 質問

なぜ最初の状態では、`fuga`のinfoログが出力されなかったのでしょうか？
私は「ルートロガー」の使い方を勘違いしているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> なぜ最初の状態では、fugaのinfoログが出力されなかったのでしょうか？

dictConfig に渡す設定に `disable_existing_loggers': False` か `'loggers': {'fuga': {}}` が必要ですが、これが指定されていないためです。

> 私は「ルートロガー」の使い方を勘違いしているのでしょうか？

rootロガーについては合っています。
fugaロガーが、dictConfigのデフォルト動作によって意図せず無効化されているのが、ログ出力されない原因です。

ロガーの初期化とdictConfigの動作は、以下の順に実行されています。

1. `fuga` ロガーは、 `from fuga import Fuga`  した時点で `logging.getLogger(__name__)` でインスタンスが作成されます。（これはよくある動作です）
2. このあと、 `logging.config.dictConfig` でロガー全体を「再初期化」していますが、 `fuga` ロガーインスタンスは既に作成されています。
3. `dictConfig` 関数は「新しい設定で上書きするか、disable_existing_loggers=Trueなら既存のロガーを無効化（削除ではない）」します。
4. `dictConfig` に渡した辞書には `fuga` ロガーの設定がなく、また `disable_existing_loggers` の指定もないため、(1)で作成済みのfugaロガーを無効化します。
5. 結果として、 `fuga` ロガー経由のログ出力は、本来であればpropagateによって親ロガー(rootロガー)に伝搬しますが、(4)で無効化されているため、なにもしません。

`dictConfig()` や `fileConfig()` でアプリケーション全体のログ出力設定を初期化するには、 `disable_existing_loggers=False` にします。例えば[Djangoのログ設定の説明](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging)でもFalseに指定するように書かれています。 https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig によると、 `disable_existing_loggers=True` がデフォルト値なのは、後方互換性のためのようです。

これに対して、 `dictConfig()` や `fileConfig()` を使わずにプログラムでloggerインスタンスを組み立てる場合、このような制約はありません。

Comment: `logging.getLogger`でインスタンスが作成されるんですね。知りませんでした。
>ロガーを直接インスタンス化することはできず、常にモジュール関数 logging.getLogger(name) を介してインスタンス化することに注意してください。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects

Answer (score 3):

理由は判明したもののベストプラクティスがまだわからない、という状況なのですけれども、ひとまず回答します。
logging.yamlに

```
disable_existing_loggers: False
```

の行がない場合、`logging.conf.dictConfig`を実行した時点で**それ以前に生成されていたロガーはすべて無効にされます**。
[ここ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/library/logging.config.html#incremental-configuration)の少し上、disable_existing_loggers の項を参照してください。

---

このことを確認するのに、

```
import logging.config

import yaml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger('fuga')
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open("logging.yaml").read()))
    logger.debug("do debug")
    logger.info("do info")
```

と

```
import logging.config

import yaml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open("logging.yaml").read()))
    logger = logging.getLogger('fuga')
    logger.debug("do debug")
    logger.info("do info")
```

の挙動の差を比較してみてください。

---

この設計(=disable_existing_loggersのデフォルト値がTrueだということ)だと、
ユーザレベルのモジュールのロガーの設定を`logging.config`モジュールの関数でおこなうのは、ユーザレベルのモジュールインポートより**前**でなければならない
ということなのでしょうか??
それが本当に設計者の意図なのか? という疑問でいっぱいですが、ひとまず。

Comment: 一般的に disable_existing_loggers=Falseにします。
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Answer (score -1):

追記:この回答は間違っているので他の方の回答を参考にしてください。

--

`fuga.py`の中で
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`
と書いておられますが、`__name__`はファイル名を表すので、実際に実行されるのは
`logger = logging.getLogger('fuga')`
となります。

つまり、'fuga'という名前のロガーを取得しています。そして、元の`logging.yaml`ではその名前のロガーは定義していないのでログは出力されません。(`logging.yaml`に'fuga'を追記するとログが出力されたのは、プログラム側が呼び出してるロガーが定義されたからです)

「ルートロガー」を利用されたいのであれば、以下のように記載すると良いと思います。
`logger = logging.getLogger()`

以下、ドキュメントも参考になります。
[logging --- Python 用ロギング機能 — Python 3.7.3rc1 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)